# Express JS conditional routing -How to route Multiple payment gateways?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, paypal, razorpay

Hello everyone so I am implementing two payment gateways i.e Paypal and Razorpay. Paypal alone works well and I want to include Razorpay as well when a condition is satisfied. But I am unsure as to where to put the code and how to classify the route by condition. Is there any way to solve this ? Thank you

Server.js

```
app.get('/api/config/paypal',(req,res) => {

     res.send(process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID)
})

app.get('/api/config/paytm',(req,res) => {

     //What do I put here?
})
```

orderController.js

```
const updateOrderToPaid = asyncHandler(async (req,res) => {
    const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id)


    if (order.paymentMethod === 'Paypal') { //Here is the condition
        order.isPaid = true
        order.paidAt = Date.now()
        order.paymentResult = {
            id: req.body.id,
            status: req.body.status,
            update_time: req.body.update_time,
            email_address: req.body.payer.email_address
        }
        const updatedOrder = await order.save()
        res.json(updatedOrder)

    }else if(order.paymentMethod === 'Paytm'){ //Here is the condition
            const options = {
                amount: order.totalPrice,
                currency,
                receipt: Date.now(),
                payment_capture
            }
    
            const razorpay = new Razorpay({
                key_id: 'rzp_test_zsLrxBdRNh3GsJ',
                key_secret: 'qyNk8fVmYi2lqOQC3SR9tjWC'
            })
            const response = await razorpay.orders.create(options)
            order.isPaid = true
            order.paidAt = Date.now()
            order.paymentResult = {
                id: response.id,
                currency: response.currency,
                receipt: response.receipt,
                payment_capture: 1,
                amount:response.amount
            }
            const updatedOrder = await order.save()
            res.json(updatedOrder)
    }else {
        
        res.status(404)
        throw new Error('Order not found')
    }
})
```

orderRoutes.js

```
const protect = require('../middleware/auth')
router.route('/:id/pay').put(protect,updateOrderToPaid)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use a provider as param in your route

```
app.get('/api/config/:provider',(req,res) => {

    const { provider } = req.params
   
   if(provider === 'paypal'){
    
       // do something related to paypal    

   }

 if(provider === 'Paytm'){
    
      // do something related to Paytm    

 }


})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes but I want to keep the conditions in the updateOrderToPaid method because it is single handedly passed into orderRoutes file. In server.js I just want to send the json response. It was easy for paypal because you need to send only client id but here with razorpay you need to send whole response and I am really confused among the above three files